# Cross Tabulation vs Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, odds-ratio

I ran a logistic regression with 20 variables. This model is to figure out what factors contribute to a greater likelihood of being a donor.
Dependent Variable= donor (y/n) (1/0)
Independent Variable in question = BEC member (y/n) (1/0)
I ran the logistic regression and MLE for BEC was -.4265 and the odds ratio was .426.  The odds ratio seems to say that for every person who is a BEC member there is a less likelihood that they donate.
This doesn't seem to be consistent with the cross tab because if someone is a BEC member then they seem to have a much greater chance of being a donor. Am I reading the cross tab incorrectly? Or was there something wrong with my logistic regression model?

[image]

Comment: It looks to me that the categories (donor/non-donor) have been flipped in your logistic regression. It could be that your software reversed the labels , e.g., it took the first category as the 'event' and it happened to be 0. Might be worth checking it out

Comment: I thought the same thing but my code had model donor(event='1')

Comment: Would the Odds Ratio for this be 18.67?
150/22462 = .0066/.9933 = .006723
14/38895 = .00036/.9996 = .00036
.006723 / .00036 = 18.67?

Comment: When I ran the same logistic regression model with ONLY the BEC variable the odds ratio came out to be 18.67. If I run it with all 20 variables then the odds ratio is .426. Why is there such a difference?

Comment: It is good that you mention this. I thought you ran the logistic regression only with BEC and Donor before as well. One reason for this large difference could be a strong correlation between BEC and another variable. Check whether BEC highly correlates with any of the other 19 variables. Then, run the model once with all 20 variables and once with those correlating variables removed. If BEC has a coefficient close to the 18.67 in the latter case, you have found the problem.

Comment: I ran a correlation of all the ivs and the highest correlation between BEC and another variable was .06.  This morning I ran multiple logistic regression models each time adding in another variable and tracking the difference in odds ratios ().  1 - BEC (18.59)  2 - BEC(12) Married (4.43)   3 - BEC (10) Married (4.2) Prof. Suffix (3.3)  4 - BEC (9.9) Married (4.1) Prof Suffix (3.2) AlsoParent (2.8) Faculty (2.45).  It seems as though with adding just 3 variables BEC was split in half but the c statistic increased in the model.

Comment: I suggest to collect the discussion in 1 thread:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278960/odds-ratio-decreases-after-every-variable-entered